# FullCalendar event unable to populate. Even though able to var_dump variable

Tags: javascript, database, laravel, laravel-5, fullcalendar

Below is the code which generates the events for the fullcalendar

```
events: [
    <?php $count=count($getBooking);$i=1;foreach($getBooking as $singleBooking){ ?>
    {
        title:'{{$singleBooking->roomLocation}}',
        start:'{{$singleBooking->bookingDate}}T{{$singleBooking->bookingTime}}',
        msg: 'Time: {{$singleBooking->bookingTime}} to {{$singleBooking->bookingTime+'03:00:00'}}:00:00<br>Course Name: {{$singleBooking->courseName}}<br>Room Name: {{$singleBooking->roomName}}<br>Service: {{$singleBooking->serviceName}}',
    }
    <?php if ($count > $i) { echo ',';}?><?php $i++; }?>
]
```

Comment: There is no `msg` attribute for full calendar https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ Display the message in the title instead

Comment: i am able to display it on my mac, however when my groupmate try to run it on his com, he is unable to see the events. maybe the inline php has a problem?

Comment: Check the console in your group-mate's browser for any errors.